# Lost support in Xamarin for GCM.Client with Android v5

Tags: android, xamarin, google-cloud-messaging

I've been working on a Xamari project, however, after I started using Android v5, many packages started showing (including GCM.Client) "Assembly not found for framework Xamarin.Android v5 Support"

Changing the Android Target Version back did not solve the issue.

Comment: Did you updated all the packages? Xamarin did moved a lot of functions to NuGet packages, all the Google Play services are now on a NuGet package, search for GCM and you will find it on the package manager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that updating the packages was the answer, but before that I had to manually delete the Components which the packages referenced and then reinstall them, that did the trick for me.